# wordpress get the first 4 and then the second 4 posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I am making a wordpress template. I have a news category.

I want to display the first 4 posts in 1 column, and the next 4 in the second column and all the remainder in column3. I know how to create the columns and so forth.

My questions is how do i actually get at the first 4, and the second 4 and then the remaining posts after I have started the query.

```
query_posts('cat=145');
```

Thanks

Comment: You can do this in **one** query, and also **never ever** use `query_posts`, it breaks the main query object and page functionalities like pagination and related posts. Use the build in loop counter, `$current_post` (which starts at `0`) and then open and close your divs according to the loop counter

Comment: thanks - really helpful

Answer (score -1):

you can use [offset](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters) in query_post, as query_post uses [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) in the backend

```
// First four posts
query_posts('cat=145&posts_per_page=4');

// Second four posts
query_posts('cat=145&posts_per_page=4&offset=4');
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: You can do everything in **one** query, also, never ever use `query_posts`, it break the main query object

Comment: @PieterGoosen he is using `query_post` in his question that's why i've used query_post,however i've also mention in answer that query_post is using WP_Query in the backend so what is the problem with the answer? and yes it can be possible in one query how ever he doesn't share the markup with it, that's why i've just shared the query_post solution, which i think is correct

Comment: Appreciate your answer Touqeer. Am a bit lost in the discussion about which is best. I  did notice in the codex that it says to avoid query_post so I used @PieterGoosen's answer, and altered my own code to avoid query_post ... at least on this template.

Comment: @maxelcat replace query post with `$my_query = new WP_Query('cat=145&posts_per_page=4');` and then try